# Window.open + Mobile Devices + Canvas == Not working?

Tags: javascript, android, ipad, mobile, canvas

I have a "button" I've created inside of the  element. It is a simple path that detects if you're in it, and if you've clicked it or have your finger on it. If you do, it executes:

```
window.open("http://www.google.com");
```

It works great in the browser, but I've tested it on an iPad, Android(2.2) phone, and Android Tablet (3.2) and it will not open a new window.

Here is a jsfiddle I put together demonstrating this:

With Code: http://jsfiddle.net/JgrU4/

Just the Result: http://jsfiddle.net/JgrU4/embedded/result/

Any ideas on how I might accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oddly enough, it seems to work if you give it a size..

```
var windowSize = "width=" + window.innerWidth + ",height=" + window.innerHeight + ",scrollbars=no";
window.open('http://www.google.com', 'popup', windowSize);
```

Tested on iOS and Android.