# How to open mobile browser on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

How to open mobile browser on javascript?

I have an App. I want to open a link to the external browser.

Here's the code that I did:

```
window.open('www.twitter.com,', '_blank');
```

But it's not working.

Here's some additional code:

```
function(e)
{
navigator.notification.alert(
    'Please login to Twitter to share your score.',// message
        function()
        {
         window.open('www.twitter.com,', '_blank');
        },// callback
        'Twitter Login',// title
        'Ok'// buttonName
         );
})
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: either the mobile phone/browser you are testing on is so incredibly old that it doesn't support that function (or js in general) or else your mobile browser blocked the popup - which is a common thing for browsers to do these days, esp when the target url doesn't match the original page's domain

Comment: I'm testing it on iPhone 5. The link opens but not on a browser. It open the link on the App itself.

Comment: so what are you saying, that you have an app and you want the app to start another program (a browser) on the phone?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Sorry for not elaborating properly.

Comment: this question answer is solved in  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946162/window-open-mobile-devices-canvas-not-working][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946162/window-open-mobile-devices-canvas-not-working

Comment: I tried that one. Still not working. Sorry.

Comment: are  you using phonegap ??

Comment: Yes. I'm using phonegap.

Comment: u need to install  phonegap local plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser to work both ans.

Comment: which phonegap version are you using ??  you are building app for android or ios ??

Comment: I'm using Version 3.4.0. I'm building it on iOS. My test device is iPhone 5 with the latest version of iOS 7 (Version 7.1).

Comment: i solved it already. reinstalled the plugin. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your target to `_system`

```
window.open("https://www.facebook.com", "_system");
```

If that doesn't work try the standard `_blank`.

```
window.open("https://www.facebook.com", "_blank");
```

Comment: It opens the link, but not on an external browser. It opens the link into the App itself. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a framework to run JS from a native app?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Version 3.4.0

Comment: In any case are you using jquery mobile?

Comment: This is the correct way to open URLs in Safari, so something else must be happening. Are you using any other JS frameworks or plugins etc? Can you post all your code, or at least your JS here/in pastebin/fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I used this in my PhoneGap app and it works for me

```
window.open('http://192.168.1.140/meplan/uploads/ielts-writing-prepositions.pdf', '_blank');
```

// use  your facebook url  it will work

You can see the Phonegap documentation [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser) that might be helpful to you

Comment: Did it open the mobile browser?

Comment: yes it opened the mobile browser .  I tested it both in  tablet as well as ipad you can use _system instead of _blank .

Comment: do you have inApp browser plugin installed ??

Comment: try to test your app in other device