# Event Listener for a click event that works on desktop and mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

```
$(document).on("ready", function(){
  var backgroundTimer = setInterval( showDiv, 4000 )
  function showDiv(){
    $("p").hide();
    $("body").css("background", "rgb(23, 22, 23)")
    $("body").on('tap touchstart click', function(){
      window.open('home.html')  
    });
  };
});
```

1.This code works for the desktop.  The click event will not work for mobile.  It will not render a new page when the body is turned into a button.

Can anyone help me here? I am a new developer. Thank you!

Comment: Try [giving the window a size](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10607895/2397327)?

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `.on()` inside your interval function - you're binding *additional* tap/touchstart/click event handlers every four seconds, which doesn't make sense for desktop *or* mobile...

Comment: why is your event listener attached every 4 seconds?... IMO, your listener should be attached just once... another thing it seems really general to have an event listener over your whole `body`... what if the user clicks on a button to execute another action? I suggest to have an invisible div over the whole page and attach the event to that.... but again, just attach the listener once.

Comment: I am having my page go black after 4 seconds, then when they click comes a really cool light effect/transition.